# Non-greedy search for beginning of string

Tags: python, regex, non-greedy

I have the following links to be extracted:

```
[{"file":"https:\/\/www.rapidvideo.com\/loadthumb.php?v=FFIMB47EWD","kind":"thumbnails"}], 
    "sources": [
        {"file":"https:\/\/www588.playercdn.net\/85\/1\/e_q8OBtv52BRyClYa_w0kw\/1496784287\/170512\/359E33j28Jo0ovY.mp4",
         "label":"Standard (288p)","res":"288"},
        {"file":"https:\/\/www726.playercdn.net\/86\/1\/q64Rsb8lG_CnxQAX6EZ2Sw\/1496784287\/170512\/371lbWrqzST1OOf.mp4"
```

I would like to extract the links ending in mp4

My regex is as follows:

```
"file":"(https\:.*?\.mp4)"
```

However, I matches are wrong as the first link ending in a php is matched.
I am practising here [Pythex.org](http://pythex.org/?regex=%22file%22%3A%22(https%5C%3A.*%3F%5C.mp4)%22&test_string=%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22home_video%22%20style%3D%22width%3A%20100%25%3B%20height%3A%20270px%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cscript%3Evar%20secs%20%3D%200%3B%20var%20lastp%20%3D%200%3B%20var%20runc%20%3D%200%3B%20jwplayer.key%20%3D%20%22O0rbeJxNgb0uLCCzJVb4yCHD46CBXw0uno5uUQ%3D%3D%22%3B%20var%20playerInstance%20%3D%20jwplayer(%22home_video%22).setup(%7B%22autostart%22%3A%20false%2C%22controls%22%3A%20true%2C%22flashplayer%22%3A%20%22%2Fjwplayer7%2Fjwplayer.flash.swf%22%2C%22image%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww755.playercdn.net%2Fthumb%2F0%2F170512%2F361d69yIyOIFcjx.jpg%22%2C%20ga%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%20%22mute%22%3A%20false%2C%20%20%22ph%22%3A%201%2C%20%20%22preload%22%3A%20%22metadata%22%2C%20%20%22primary%22%3A%20%22html%22%2C%20%20%22repeat%22%3A%20false%2C%20%20%22skin%22%3A%20%7B%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22tube%22%20%20%7D%2C%20%20%22stagevideo%22%3A%20true%2C%20%20%22stretching%22%3A%20%22uniform%22%2C%20%20%22visualplaylist%22%3A%20true%2C%20%20%22width%22%3A%20%22100%25%22%2C%20%20%22aspectratio%22%3A%20%2216%3A9%22%2C%20%20%22provider%22%3A%20%27http%27%2C%20%20%22startparam%22%3A%20%22start%22%2C%20tracks%3A%20%5B%7B%22file%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.rapidvideo.com%5C%2Floadthumb.php%3Fv%3DFFIMB47EWD%22%2C%22kind%22%3A%22thumbnails%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22sources%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22file%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww588.playercdn.net%5C%2F85%5C%2F1%5C%2Fe_q8OBtv52BRyClYa_w0kw%5C%2F1496784287%5C%2F170512%5C%2F359E33j28Jo0ovY.mp4%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Standard%20(288p)%22%2C%22res%22%3A%22288%22%7D%2C%7B%22file%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww726.playercdn.net%5C%2F86%5C%2F1%5C%2Fq64Rsb8lG_CnxQAX6EZ2Sw%5C%2F1496784287%5C%2F170512%5C%2F371lbWrqzST1OOf.mp4%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22High%20(576p)%22%2C%22res%22%3A%22576%22%2C%22default%22%3A%22true%22%7D%5D%20%2C%22logo%22%3A%20%7B%20%20%20%20%22file%22%3A%20%22%22%2C%20%20%20%20%22logoBar%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rapidvideo.com%2Fimages%2Frapidvideo_logo_player.png%22%2C%20%22target%22%3A%20%22blank%22%2C%20%22hide%22%3A%20true%2C%20%20%20%20%22link%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rapidvideo.com%22%2C%20%20%20%20%22margin%22%3A%20%225%22%2C%20%20%20%20%22position%22%3A%20%22top-right%22%20%20%7D%2C%22displaydescription%22%3A%20false%2C%22displaytitle%22%3A%20false%20%2C%20%22abouttext%22%3A%20%22RapidVideo%20Player%22%2C%20%22aboutlink%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rapidvideo.com%22%20%20%7D)%3B%20playerInstance.on(%27ready%27%2Cfunction()%20%7B%20%2F*%20jwLogoBar.addLogo(playerInstance)%3B%20*%2F%20%7D)%3B%20playerInstance.on(%27time%27%2C%20function(event)%20%7B%20if(runc%20%3D%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%20var%20time%3D%20Math.floor(event.position)%3B%20if(time%20%3E%20lastp%2B10)%20%7B%20if(lastp%20!%3D%20time)%20%7B%20lastp%20%3D%20time%3B%20%24.getJSON(%22%2F%3Fc%3Dl%26i%3DFFIMB47EWD%26o%3D9786ea7fcb8c58b434f79a88754c773c%26a%3D%22%2BcanRunAds%2C%20function(%20data%20)%20%7Bif(data.status%20%3D%3D%201)%20%7B%20runc%20%3D%201%3B%20%7D%20%7D)%3B%20%7D%7D%20%20%7D%20%7D)%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Evar%20jt%20%3D%20setInterval(t%2C%20(5*1000))%3Bvar%20tp%20%3D%200%3Bvar%20ttt%20%3D%200%3Bvar%20tt%20%3D%20true%3Bfunction%20t()%7Bif(tt%20%3D%3D%20false)%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20clearInterval(jt)%3B%20return%20false%3B%20%7Dif(jwplayer(%22home_video%22).getState().toLowerCase()%20%3D%3D%20%27playing%27)%20%7B%20tp%20%3D%20tp%2B5%3B%20%7Dif(ttt%20%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%20ttt%20%3D%20jwplayer(%22home_video%22).getDuration()%3B%20%7D%20else%20%7Bp%20%3D%200%3B%20if(tp%20%3E%200)%7Bp%20%3D%20(parseInt(tp)%2FparseInt(ttt))*100%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Dif(p%20%3E%200)%7Btt%20%3D%20false%3B%20%2F*%20%24.get(%22%2F%3Fc%3Dl%26i%3DFFIMB47EWD%26o%3D9786ea7fcb8c58b434f79a88754c773c%26a%3D%22)%3B%20*%2F%20%7D%7D%7D%3C%2Fscript%3E&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0). How do I avoid the first link?
The link to the html page I am trying to parse is https://www.rapidvideo.com/e/FFIMB47EWD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why even use regular expressions? This looks like a JSON object/Python dict, you could just iterate through it and use [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=endswith#str.endswith).

```
>>> sources = {
...     "sources": [
...         {"file": "https:\/\/www588.playercdn.net\/85\/1\/e_q8OBtv52BRyClYa_w0kw\/1496784287\/170512\/359E33j28Jo0ovY.mp4",
...          "label": "Standard (288p)","res":"288"},
...         {"file": "https:\/\/www726.playercdn.net\/86\/1\/q64Rsb8lG_CnxQAX6EZ2Sw\/1496784287\/170512\/371lbWrqzST1OOf.mp4",
...          "label": "Standard (288p)","res":"288"}
...     ]
... }
>>> for item in sources['sources']:
...     if item['file'].endswith('.mp4'):
...         print(item['file'])
... 
https:\/\/www588.playercdn.net\/85\/1\/e_q8OBtv52BRyClYa_w0kw\/1496784287\/170512\/359E33j28Jo0ovY.mp4
https:\/\/www726.playercdn.net\/86\/1\/q64Rsb8lG_CnxQAX6EZ2Sw\/1496784287\/170512\/371lbWrqzST1OOf.mp4
```

EDIT:

It looks like that link is available in a `video` tag after the javascript has loaded. You could use a headless browser but I just used `selenium` to  fully load the page and then save the html.

After you have the full page html, you can parse it using `BeautifulSoup` instead of regular expressions.

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


def extract_mp4_link(page_html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'lxml')
    return soup.find('video')['src']


def get_page_html(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    driver.close()
    return page_source


if __name__ == '__main__':
    page_url = 'https://www.rapidvideo.com/e/FFIMB47EWD'
    page_html = get_page_html(page_url)
    print(extract_mp4_link(page_html))
```

Comment: BUt this is the javascript code within a html source

Comment: @EchchamaNayak I edited my answer to include code that seems to extract the link you are looking for. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Sorry. I saw it now. Thanks